# Excel - Remove All Text Before A Character In Sequence

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cells that contain text in this format:

```
Category 1>Category 2>Category 3>Category 4
Category 1>Category 2
Category 1>Category 2>Category 3
Category 1
```

...and so on. I would like to run a formula that removes all before the last entry in the sequence. So the above would output as:

```
Category 4
Category 2
Category 3
Category 1
```

I've tried using this formula but it obviously removes only the text before the first delimiter in the sequence:

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(">",A2))
```

How do I adapt the formula to achieve what I want to do? Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,">",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)))
```

Drag/Copy down as required.

[image]